# Handle multiple file selection

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following code:

```
void OpenJpgFile(HWND hWnd)
{
OPENFILENAME ofn;
wchar_t szFileName[17*MAX_PATH] = L"";

ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
ofn.lpstrTitle = L"Selecione as fotos que deseja adicionar...";
ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Arquivos JPEG (*.jpg)\0*.jpg\0Todos os Arquivos (*.*)\0*.*\0";
ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT;
ofn.lpstrDefExt = L"jpg";
if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
{
            //Test
    MessageBox(hWnd,ofn.lpstrFileTitle,L"TESTE",NULL);


            if(gpBitmap)
    {
        delete gpBitmap;
    }
    gpBitmap = new Bitmap(szFileName);

        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    }
}
```

What I wanted to know is how can I get the name of all files the user has selected...

All I can get is the path to the folder... is there an array that keeps the file names?

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: This is a major pain point of the XP file dialogs. You have to decide up front how big a buffer to allocate for the file names. If the user selects too many files, your program cannot get all of the names. This is why you must switch to the Vista file dialogs, `IFileDialog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation of `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) when `OFN_EXPLORER` is also specified, `lpstrFile` will contain the directory followed by the names of the files, separated by null characters, and terminated with two adjacent null characters. When you call `new Bitmap(szFileName)` you are treating `szFileName` incorrectly - that is you pass it to a constructor that expects a standard single-null terminated string. Instead you have to process it more carefully to read past the initial null, and probably recreate your full file paths.

This string format happens to be the same format as used for [`REG_MULTI_SZ`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16563368/89999) so, aside from not having to worry about missing final terminators, advice related to handling values of type `REG_MULTI_SZ` can help you here.

Note that to be fully general, you may also have to handle cases that require a larger buffer. See [GetOpenFileName() with OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT flag set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656655/getopenfilename-with-ofn-allowmultiselect-flag-set) for another angle on that